# Creating episodeIDs for series of overlapping event pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two possible events that can happen multiple times each, call them eventA and eventB.  eventA and eventB and details about them exist on the EventA and EventB tables, they have a primary key that is an auto increment called eventAID and eventBID respectively.

I want to identify Episodes, each of which contain at least one eventA and one eventB but can have more than one of each.  I want to give each of those episodes a unique episodeID, the episodeID is an arbitrary identification number and just has to be unique to each episode.

I have some criteria (and SQL statement) that will tell me if a given eventA and a given eventB exist in the same episode.  It outputs a table with eventAID and eventBID in a row.  I call this table the Episode table.

That query is of the format:

```
SELECT EventA.eventAID, EventB.eventBID 
INTO Episode
FROM EventA 
INNER JOIN EventB ON *some criteria* 
WHERE *some criteria*;
```

I have access to and can modify this query.  There are numerous criteria involved in this pairing that are not relevant.

Example Episode table data:

```
eventAID  eventBID
123       456
124       789
125       457
125       458
126       459
127       459
128       790
128       791
129       791
```

Some eventA and eventB have no partner and I want to ignore them. (not shown, they don't appear in the Episode table)

Most eventA will pair with exactly one eventB and vice versa, each of those should get a unique episodeID.

```
episodeID  eventAID  eventBID
1          123       456
2          124       789
```

Some eventA will pair with more than one eventB and vice versa, each of those should also get the same episodeID.

```
episodeID  eventAID  eventBID
3          125       457
3          125       458
4          126       459
4          127       459
```

A few eventA will pair with more than one eventB, but one of those eventB will pair to more than one and different eventA.  All of these also receive the same episodeID.

```
episodeID  eventAID  eventBID
5          128       790
5          128       791
5          129       791
```

Note that the presented tables above are examples based on the table of all qualifying eventA-eventB pairs that my SQL statement for the criteria produces.  They are to illustrate certain cases in the data I am seeing.

The final presentation for this would be in the original EventA and EventB tables where unpaired events have been removed.  If your solution doesn't need that Episode table, feel free to do away with it.

```
episodeID  eventAID  eventAdata
1          123       *
2          124       *
3          125       *
4          126       *
4          127       *
5          128       *
5          129       *

episodeID  eventBID  eventBdata
1          456       *
2          789       *
3          457       *
3          458       *
4          459       *
5          790       *
5          791       *
```

If given the labeled episodeID table with the pairs (as above examples), I can easily do this.

---

The single pairs are not a problem.

I can detect those eventA with more than one eventB paired to them (via HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) and filter them out.  Vice versa for eventB with more than one eventA.

Removing them from the list of all pairs (via EXCEPT) will leave only pairs of eventA with only one eventB and eventB with only one eventA.  (episode 1 and 2 in the example)

Using ROW_NUMBER will generate an incrementing series of episodeID.

However, the issue is the episode 3, 4 and 5 case.

3 and 4 are symmetrical, if the eventAID or eventBIDs whose pairs do not have further pairs (the episode 5 case) can be identified, giving them episodeID can be done.

Episode 5 is much harder.  eventAID 128 links to eventBID 790 and 791, the episodeID attached to them thus propagates to eventAID 129.  If eventAID 129 was linked to a different eventBID, those also get the same episodeID, etc.

And this can continue potentially indefinitely, but longer chains are rarer than shorter ones.

The past solution was to use a Procedure that would move a row off the Episode table into a temporary table (deleting them from Episode), then move rows with event IDs that appear in the temporary table to the temporary table, and repeat until the temporary table stops growing.

Then all those rows get the same EpisodeID and written to the output table.  Empty the temporary table and repeat until Episode table is empty.

This was very suboptimal and took an extremely long time to run (1 hour+ on a 15k row Episode table).  Very bad when the episodeIDs have to be regenerated regularly.

Not to mention the bugs from being extremely complicated.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm looking for general algorithm descriptions rather than code, but code is fine too.

---

EDIT: A simple example.

EventA table

```
eventAID  pid  eventAdata  eventAdata2
123       1    1           
124       1    2           
125       2    3           
126       3    4           
127       3    4           
128       3    5           1
129       3    6           
130       4    1
```

EventB table

```
eventBID  pid  eventBdata  eventBdata2
456       1    1           
789       1    2           
457       2    3           
458       2    3           
459       3    4           
790       3    5           
791       3    6           1
```

Currently present query

```
SELECT EventA.eventAID, EventB.eventBID 
INTO Episode
FROM EventA 
INNER JOIN EventB ON EventA.pid = EventB.pid
WHERE EventA.eventAdata = EventB.eventBdata
OR EventA.eventAdata2 = EventB.eventBdata2;
```

This creates an Episode table filled with eventA and eventB pairs which are part of an episode.

```
eventAID  eventBID
123       456
124       789
125       457
125       458
126       459
127       459
128       790
128       791
129       791
```

The query and it's criteria are functionally just a test of "are these EventA and EventB part of the same episode".

I need to label EventA and EventB tables such that:

```
episodeID  eventAID  pid  eventAdata  eventAdata2
1          123       1    1           
2          124       1    2           
3          125       2    3           
4          126       3    4           
4          127       3    4           
5          128       3    5           1
5          129       3    6           

episodeID  eventBID  pid  eventBdata  eventBdata2
1          456       1    1           
2          789       1    2           
3          457       2    3           
3          458       2    3           
4          459       3    4           
5          790       3    5           
5          791       3    6           1
```

In this simple toy example, event data and event data2 are a number from 1 to 6 or null.  pid is a foreign key from another table used to identify groups of records that belong to a single person.

Further requirements:

All eventA and eventB in an episode must belong to the same person.

An episode must have at least one eventA and one eventB.

Bonus points:

Extend solution to include an EventC table with a similar style of data...

Comment: I feel that you've given us information which may not help to explain your question.  Can you _edit_ your question, and instead show sample input table data, and then the expected output?

Comment: Are the example tables not enough?  I believe I gave the format of the output of the initial query (the Episode table) and the final state of the EventA and EventB tables.

The query itself uses complex criteria that is generated by someone else but implemented by me.  It is not a straightforward overlapping date range (although that is involved), there are other variables that can change the acceptable date range, or simply exclude an event.

Additionally, the criteria used in the query is subject to change in the future.

Comment: @JonathanSeah, allow me to direct your attention to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I have added a simple example with tables and a model of my current query.  If you need something else, just reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next query.

```
with
  ee as (
    select *
    from(values
      (123, 456), (124, 789), (125, 457),
      (125, 458), (126, 459), (127, 459),
      (128, 790), (128, 791), (129, 791)
    ) t(eva, evb)
  ),
  a as (
    select *,
      row_number() over(order by eva, evb) rn,
      row_number() over(partition by eva order by evb) rna,
      row_number() over(partition by evb order by eva) rnb
    from ee
  )
select
  sum(iif(rna = 1 and rnb = 1, 1, 0)) over(order by rn) evid,
  *
from a;
```

```
evid    eva     evb
1       123     456
2       124     789
3       125     457
3       125     458
4       126     459
4       127     459
5       128     790
5       128     791
5       129     791
```

In the following query the data for the `C` events added..

```
with
  eee as (
    select *
    from(values
      (123, 456, 42), (124, 789, 42), (125, 457, 42), (125, 458, 170), (126, 459, 170),
      (127, 459, 170), (128, 790, 171), (128, 791, 171), (129, 791, 172), (130, 792, 173)
    ) t(eva, evb, evc)
  ),
  a as (
    select *,
      row_number() over(order by eva, evb, evc) rn,
      row_number() over(partition by eva order by evb, evc) rna,
      row_number() over(partition by evb order by eva, evc) rnb,
      row_number() over(partition by evc order by eva, evb) rnc
    from eee
  )
select
  sum(iif(rna = 1 and rnb = 1 and rnc = 1, 1, 0)) over(order by rn) evid,
  *
from a;
```

```
evid    eva     evb     evc
1       123     456     42
1       124     789     42
1       125     457     42
1       125     458     170
1       126     459     170
1       127     459     170
2       128     790     171
2       128     791     171
2       129     791     172
3       130     792     173
```

Both queries can be checked [here](http://rextester.com/XYONJ52446).

Comment: Oh, this is almost correct!

However, if you add a new eventBID that connects to 129 but is lower than 791, that causes 129 to split off into it's own episode.  

To replicate with your test code add to ee: , (129, 777)

-- it works if 129 is connected to an eventB that has a higher ID than 791, eg. (129, 792) works perfectly.